# Is it possible to expose a webservice from lwc in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, apexrest

I want to make a REST api call to show notification or toast message in the lwc. I have tried with Platform Events and Change Data Capture.

Is there any way to receive the REST API call in the lwc so that message can be showed when we call it

Comment: Lwc cannot receive rest api calls from apex but they can receive platform events. See answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your API could create a [Platform Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm). The lwc can listen for platform events using [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_lc.htm)